# How do I translate German passive sentences with intransitive verbs into English?

Tags: translation, german-to-english, passive

So in German I’m aware with intransitive verbs (without a direct object) you can somehow form a passive sentence out of them, which you can’t do in English to my knowledge.

My question is, how am I to go about translating them? I’m trying to illustrate some examples of them for a friend but I’m having extreme difficulty in figuring out how to actually come up with a good English translation.

**As 2 examples:**

> Es wird (von uns) zum Supermarkt gelaufen.
>
> Es wird auf der Party getanzt.

Is the solution simply not to try and translate it in such a form, and to instead give the active form of the sentence “We are walking to the supermarket” translation instead? If so how can I do that for the second one, since there is no subject given unlike in the first with *(von uns)*.

Comment: To my (non natvive) ears the first sentence sounds awkward. Are you sure, you want to translate it?

Comment: @c.p. Ah okay, if it's an awkward sounding sentence that's not likely to be used, then I guess not using the passive for it (& translating it) would be more sensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example probably needs the information on who is walking, and I would not force that into passive.

If you say "Es wird zum Supermarkt gegangen" it sounds like you stress the "walking" part (e.g, as opposed to driving) and that you order others to do it.

> Wir gehen zum Supermarkt.
>
> We'll go to the supermarket.

The 2nd example, "Es wird auf der Party getanzt" könnte man so übersetzen:

> There will be dancing at the party.

In that case it's not important who does the dancing, so you can leave that information aside.

Comment: I see, many thanks for that. It's pretty relieving to hear that the first sentence would never normally appear in passive to be honest. Thanks for helping with the second one (though wouldn't it be "there is" since it's present tense? :P).

Comment: @Rawrren Formally, _es wird auf der Party getanzt_ is not in a future tense indeed, because you’d expect _… werden_ at the end, but if obvious the present tense may still refer to a future event. English is often considered to be a bit stricter than German about its tenses.